# Wordpress permalinks (mod rewrite)

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get Wordpress up and running in a directory (/blog), but as there's a .htaccess file in the root directory I think it's conflicting when I turn on permalinks. When I try to visit a page such as http://www.domain.com/blog/2011/03/article-name/ I get a 404. I can however, visit http://www.domain.com/blog/

Here's the .htaccess from the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#If not valid file send request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Here's the .htaccess from the /blog directory:

```
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

Any ideas how I can fix the wordpress permalinks? I have access to both .htaccess files (if the solution requires editing the one in the root directory)..

Comment: The last rule is weird. I would have set `^.*$`. Regarding the conflict, what does `mydomain.com/blog/blablabla` returns ? the index of `/` ??

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried commenting out the WordPress related content in the root .htaccess file? If WP is installed in a sub directory, I believe that .htaccess file should be doing all the work

Comment: The rewrite conditions and rules in the root are required for the main website (they're all non wordpress related). It might be that I need to do a rule that says only apply them if the directory isn't /blog..